# How to allow particular domain to access drupal 7 API?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a service, which gives the information about subscribers but I want to allow to access this service to 2 or 3 my different applications, not to the public.

Comment: Take a look https://www.drupal.org/project/services_api_key_auth

Answer (score 1):

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows a web page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain. Such "cross-domain" requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same origin security policy.

you can use [cors module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cors)

This module provides a configuration page to map domains to paths and add the necessary Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.